# Capture Printed Files from a printer to device

Tags: printer, capture

I’m researching how I can obtain all the printed files on a LAN connected printer. So if multiple computers are connected to one printer, is there a way for me to be able to intercept all those printed files to a USB device or personal computer using some sort of software or usb device connected to the printer capturing those files data. Thanks

Comment: This is a service usually natively built into the printer, and often reserved for large corporate copy machines that required pin codes (think large ~$5000+ hardware).

Comment: If the printer is networked, unless there is an explicit admin functionality to cqapture print jobs like this, all traffic would be encrypted. So you can’t just “sniff” print jobs like that.

Comment: What if I have access as the admin. It’s for my business but cannot afford something as $5k. Are there any other cheaper solutions?

Comment: Have a look at https://pimylifeup.com/raspberry-pi-print-server/

Comment: Do you need the actual files, or do you just need to know how many pages were printed and by whom? With an intelligent printer, one file can print multiple copies.